# Why cc cannot find lgomp while gcc can

Tags: gcc, imagemagick, cc

on Mac OS X 10.7

I run this command on this file http://www.imagemagick.org/source/wand.c as they said here
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php

```
cc -o wand `pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand` wand.c
```

An error occurred:

```
ld: library not found for -lgomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But gcc works fine:

```
gcc -o wand `pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand` wand.c
```

Why was that? I want to know what different between gcc and cc on this.

FYI:
I installed ImageMagick follow this http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php.
The only command I didn't follow is `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib` since my Mac have no `ldconfig` here.

Comment: What does `ls -l \`which cc\`` say on your machine? On mine (a GNU/Linux), it is a soft link to the `gcc` binary. What about `cc --version` and `gcc --version`?

Comment: It's: `/usr/bin/cc -> clang`. clang 3.1

Comment: Well, I just found this: [Comparison of Diagnostics between GCC and Clang](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ClangDiagnosticsComparison). Thanks, @ArjunShankar

Comment: clang (which is *not* GCC) does not support OpenMP (yet).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I didn't mean that link answered my question ;)

Comment: Actually, what I said doesn't answer your question either. I wouldn't expect `clang` not to find `libgomp`. I would expect it to ignore the OpenMP `#pragma`s. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Hi, ArjunShankar. You deleted your answer --! I have read it. It's kind of informational :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: I didn't think it fair to 'answer' because I didn't completely answer your question. It wasn't worth anything more than a comment. Anyway, good luck.