# How do I get a homebrewed version of GDB working on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, gdb, homebrew

I am trying to debug a C++ program in Eclipse using gdb. I think it works fine in my `main()` function, but elsewhere it gives me a warning when I try to look at the value of a variable:

```
Failed to execute MI command:
-data-evaluate-expression variable
Error message from debugger back end:
Could not find the frame base for "Class::method()".`
```

After scouring the internet, I am having a hard time understanding what this error means or finding out how to fix the problem. There are a few other similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843730/problems-with-gdb-7-5-1-debugging-executable-built-via-g-4-7-2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430972/debugging-problems-with-macports-gcc-on-os-x)) floating around Stack Overflow.

Since Apple's Xcode command line tools are painfully out-of-date (see [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795742/why-cc-cannot-find-lgomp-while-gcc-can) and [gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067569/gdb-does-not-break-on-some-lines-of-code-when-using-multiple-source-files) issues) I needed to use my own homebrewed versions. I don't know if there is something in the setup for these tools that I might have missed.

I can debug from command line using gdb and I hit the same error: `"Could not find the frame base for "Class::method()"`, so I'm pretty sure it is not an issue with Eclipse.

Does anything jump out to anyone, that might be causing this problem?

- Mac OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion)
- Eclipse 4.2.1 (Juno)
- gcc 4.8.2 (homebrewed) (with `-O0` and `-g3`)
- gdb 7.6.2 (homebrewed and codesigned)

**Update:**

I am also seeing the line:

```
BFD: /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork(i386:x86-64): unknown load command 0x20
```

Followed by several warnings:

```
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/private/tmp/gcc48-KqoQ/gcc-4.8.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/libstdc++-v3/src/../libsupc++/.libs/libsupc++convenience.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/private/tmp/gcc48-KqoQ/gcc-4.8.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/libstdc++-v3/src/../src/c++11/.libs/libc++11convenience.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/private/tmp/gcc48-KqoQ/gcc-4.8.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/libstdc++-v3/src/../src/c++98/.libs/libc++98convenience.a"
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc48-KqoQ/gcc-4.8.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility-atomic-c++0x.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc48-KqoQ/gcc-4.8.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility-c++0x.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc48-KqoQ/gcc-4.8.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility-chrono.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc48-KqoQ/gcc-4.8.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility-debug_list-2.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
...
```

which continues for several lines. Google searches for "gdb bfd unknown load command" reveal a lot of sites without any solution, but they all seem to indicate that there may be a conflict between non-apple versions of gdb and Mac OS X 10.8+.

Any insight would help a ton!

Comment: I just opened a thread about something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414707. I have had success using XCode 5.1 with llvm-gcc as the compiler and gcc 7.7.1 as the debugger but I'm still interested in answers to how to solve this.

Comment: Same problem here. Thanks in advance for anyone who can solve it.

Comment: I'm not an expert by any means but you can try compiling with -gdwarf-3 flag and see if it works.

Comment: the -g flag rings a bell for fixing some previous problem I had.  Is there no package available with all this stuff fixed up though, maybe "http://brew.sh/" if that isn't what you meant by homebrewed?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you using LLDB/Clang? As to the original question, how did you install GCC and what is the compiler invocation?

Comment: @JonathanHoward I needed GCC for OpenMP support. I installed GCC through homebrew. Ultimately, I ended up debugging using a build on an Ubuntu virtual machine.

Comment: @NealKruis, there is a clang fork with omp, very easily installable with brew, `brew install clang-omp` IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the name mangling. Names are mangled same with GCC and Clang (they often share similar mechanisms). Name mangling makes it available to have C/C++ method and Assembly procedure with the same name. See what happens to a C definition:

```
void myfunc() {}
```

We use `nm` to view binary names of symbols. Use `nm --demangle` to view unmangled names. Nm output for compiled file is:
    ...
    0000000000000000 T _myfunc
    ...
Number of other symbols depends on debugging level, see GCC manpage for -O and -g options. As we see, there is a number. It's hexadecimal. It has eight digits on 32bit machines and sixteen digits on 64bit machines (it's because n-bit CPU means that n-bits represent a pointer, the symbol is really a pointer inside the binary file). Then we have symbol type. Only two values are interesting now: `T` is a C/C++/... method, `t` is an assembler procedure. See what goes on if we compile following assembly code:

```
myproc:
```

GCC and Clang shouldn't push debugging symbols when compiling Assembly, so `nm` output will probably look like:

```
0000000000000000 t myproc
```

Assembly procedure names are not mangled. C++ is mangled, very strangely. Some characters, like `:` or `,` are not allowed in symbol name. Compile this C++ source:

```
namespace myspace { void myfunc() {} }
```

We see output:

```
...
0000000000000000 T __ZN7myspace6myfuncEv
...
```

And main method name is never mangled. If we have like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {}
int main(std::vector<std::string> args) {}
```

only the second name is mangled. I think this may be the problem. And, these warnings mean NOTHING. They mean that system was recompiled with low debugging symbol count.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with mangling. Apparently debugging symbols are not contained in libraries on mac os, which confuses gdb.